# JSON key is missing (using @JsonComponent on Spring-boot with kotlin)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

Thanks reading this question.

this problem confused me.
I created code that response JSON data like below.

```
@RestController
class JsonTestController {

    @GetMapping("jsonTest")
    fun jsonTest(): ResponseEntity<HaveBoolean> {
        val value = BooleanValue(true)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HaveBoolean(value))
    }

    data class BooleanValue(val value: Boolean)

    data class HaveBoolean(
        val isAdmin: BooleanValue,
    )
}
```

and @JsonComponent is below.

```
@JsonComponent
class BooleanValueJson {

    class Serializer : JsonSerializer<JsonTestController.BooleanValue>() {
        override fun serialize(value: JsonTestController.BooleanValue, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
            gen.writeBoolean(value.value)
        }
    }

    class Deserializer : JsonDeserializer<JsonTestController.BooleanValue>() {
        override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): JsonTestController.BooleanValue =
            JsonTestController.BooleanValue(p.valueAsBoolean)
    }
}
```

When I request `localhost://8082/jsonTest`, I got empty json (`{}`).
but, I tried other variable name like `hoge`, mean coding like below.

```
    data class HaveBoolean(
        val hoge: BooleanValue,
    )
```

then, I request again, I can get correctly json (`{"hoge": true}`).

Can't I use `isAdmin`　name on data class ?

Do you have any idea why this problem is happening?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with jackson in kotlin. Jackson basically tries to remove `is` from the name but kotlin data class implementation doesn't have a proper getter without "is" resulting in mismatch. You can add `JsonProperty("isAdmin")` to the variable and it should work.

```
data class HaveBoolean(
    @get:JsonProperty("isAdmin")
    val isAdmin: BooleanValue,
)
```